# Simple ORM with relationships

Tags: c#, orm, windows-runtime

Any recommendations for an ORM that will support relationships for Windows 8 / WP8?

```
class Person {
    int id;
    int Name;
    List<Address> Addresses;
}

class Address {
    int id;
    string Street;
    string Country;
}
```

If you do create table on person it should create the Address table too, and any select queries on Person would also return the associated address. I know EF/nHibernate do this, but unfortunately we don't have System.Data anymore with WinRT.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905084/can-i-use-entity-framework-or-linq-to-sql-with-windows-8-metro-style-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best option is probably to use [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) which is a micro ORM for SQLite

Tim Heuer has an article on this here.
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

Comment: I see this is an older response, but the link appears to be about getting sqllite to run in metro app, but doesn't have anything to do with ORM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905084/can-i-use-entity-framework-or-linq-to-sql-with-windows-8-metro-style-apps?lq=1