# Using NHibernate in a Metro

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am porting an app from iOS to Win8 and would like to use NHibernate in the app to store relational data, but whenever I add the `NHibernate.dll` & `lesli.Collections.dll` I get the following errors:

Error   2   Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module mscorlib.dll.

Error   1   Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Data.dll'

If someone could point me in the direction of possible solution that would be great, I've been unable to find one as of yet

Comment: are you trying to use NHibernate in a winrt app?

Comment: Yes, I would like to target WinRT. But the main goal is that this becomes a Store App. From testing different templates, it seem Windows Store Apps have a portion of the .NET Framework removed. In this case I think NHibernate relies on System.Data (Which has been removed from the Windows Store .NET Framework) to connect to a Database, so if you know of another library that can connect to a SQLite DB I would be very grateful

Comment: see here, someone already seems to have a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905084/can-i-use-entity-framework-or-linq-to-sql-with-windows-8-metro-style-apps

Comment: +1 for using NHibernate in a Metro.

Comment: Cheers for that Dirk, if you post that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4):

It seems System.Data is not available for Windows Store applications. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2012/09/data-devs-local-access-windows-store.aspx NHibernate relies heavily on System.Data.

Comment: I've said that it relies on System.Data, im after another option