# dotCMIS in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, sharepoint, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

I would like to use the great functionalities exposed by the CMIS standard to connect to Alfresco and Sharepoint from my app. I've found the dotCMIS library by Apache Chemestry but i'm not able to use in my Windows Store App. In particular i import in the project the DotCMIS.dll library and then in my first class:

```
SessionFactory session = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
```

This will cause an error at runtime: "Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module mscorlib.dll"

Is there a way to do this or maybe another solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not able to use in my Windows Store App"? You don't know how? There's some restriction? You're getting an error? Something else?

Comment: you're right, i was too generic. I've edit the question with more details.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926502/using-nhibernate-in-a-metro) looks related - same exception there from a different Open Source library