# How to map sqlite tables and columns to c# classes in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sqlite

I'm building an my first app (I'm a complete noob) in C# for windows 8. And I have some classes that I have created. When the app runs it needs to read data from a sqlite database. I have a class for each table, but I don't know how to map each class property to its respective column in the database.
I can't seem to find any info and all the stuff I've seen seems to map them automatically or doesn't mention how it's done e.g.

```
public class Person
{
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }

[MaxLength(30)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[MaxLength(30)]
public string Surname { get; set; }

}
```

Sample

```
var query = conn.Table<Person>().Where(x => x.Name == "Matteo");
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} {2}", item.Id, item.Name, item.Surname));
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or a tutorial of some sort? I've never worked with sqlite before.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10905084

Comment: are you creating the table before querying it? conn.CreateTable<Person>();

Comment: No the tables already exist in the database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I feel foolish... it turns out you have to set the table and column attributes on the class.
eg

```
[Table("sometable")]
class Element
{
    [Column(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("columnone")]
    public string PropertyOne {get; set;}

    [Column("columntwo")]
    public string PropertyTwo {get; set;}
}
```