# Mapping sqlite tables and c# classes for query, insert and update

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is there any way to map a class to a sqlite table?

For instance, if I have a Person class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}
    public string BirthDate {get; set;}
}
```

Is there any way to automatically insert any object into a table that shares the same name as the class and the same columns as its attributes? I thought it would be possible going by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104031/how-to-map-sqlite-tables-and-columns-to-c-sharp-classes-in-windows-8), but I can't find the exact package that was being used in that case nor if it really does what I would want.

Comment: The term you're looking for is called "Object Relational Mapper" or ORM. There are plenty of different ones available, which you can find with a little bit of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object-relational mapper (ORM) such as `Entity Framework`. Please refer to the "Get Started" links on the following MSDN page for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/

**Getting Started with EF Core on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) with a New Database:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

**SQLite EntityFramework 6 Tutorial:** https://erazerbrecht.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/sqlite-entityframework-6-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you need an ORM. I suggest Dapper, very fast and distributed by those running the site we're on. Also, take a look at Automapper which may help you in the process of transforming your data objects in domain objects and back.

#### Dapper on GitHub

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

#### Automapper on GitHub

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper